# How to get the shortest path in graph between two vertexes?

Tags: python

I have a class WeightedAdjacencyMatrix. It contains matrix:

```
class WeightedAdjacencyMatrix:
    """A weighted graph represented as a matrix."""

    __slots__ = ['_W']

    def __init__(self, size, edges=[], weights=[]):
        """Initializes a weighted adjacency matrix for a graph with size nodes.

        Graph is initialized with size nodes and a specified set of
        edges and edge weights.

        Keyword arguments:
        size -- Number of nodes of the graph.
        edges -- a list of ordered pairs (2-tuples) indicating the
                 edges of the graph.  The default value is an empty list
                 which means no edges by default.
        weights -- a list of weights for the edges, which should be the same
                   length as the edges list.  The position of a value in
                   the weights list corresponds to the edge in the same
                   position of the edges list.
        """
        self._W = [[math.inf] * size for _ in range(size)]

        for i in range(size):
            self._W[i][i] = 0

        for edge, weight in zip(edges, weights):
            self.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight)

    def add_edge(self, u, v, weight):
        """Adds an undirected edge between u to v with the specified weight.

        Keyword arguments:
        u -- vertex id (0-based index)
        v -- vertex id (0-based index)
        weight -- edge weight
        """

        self._W[u][v] = weight
        self._W[v][u] = weight

    def floyd_warshall(self):
        """Floyd Warshall algorithm for all pairs shortest paths.

        Returns a matrix D consisting of the weights of the shortest
        paths between all pairs of vertices, and a matrix P for
        the predecessors matrix (what the textbook called PI).
        This method MUST NOT change the weight matrix of the graph
        itself.
        """
        # Your return statement will look something like this one
        # in the comment on the following line.  That returns
        # the two matrices, with the D matrix first.  The return None
        # is just a placeholder so that this is valid Python syntax before
        # you've completed the assignment.  This comment line is
        # more like what it should look like:
        # return D, P

        n = len(self._W)

        # Create a deep copy of the weight matrix.
        D = copy.deepcopy(self._W)

        # Initialize the predecessor matrix to None.
        P = [[None]*n for _ in range(n)]

        # Compute shortest paths between all pairs of vertices.
        for k in range(n):
            for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                    if D[i][k] + D[k][j] < D[i][j]:
                        D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j]
                        P[i][j] = k

        return D, P
```

Also I have to implement pair_shortest_path() function:

```
def pair_shortest_path(D, P, s, t):
    """EXTRA CREDIT: This function takes D and P matrices (i.e., what is generated
    by floyd_warshall), and a source vertex (where you want to start) and
    destination or target vertex t (where you want to end up) and
    returns a pair: w, path, such that w is the weight of the shortest
    path from s to t (just a simple lookup in the D matrix) and
    path is a Python list of vertex ids starting at s and ending at t
    derived from the P matrix. If no path exists from s to t, then returns
    math.inf for w (which is what D[s][t] should be in that case), and an
    empty list for the path.

    Keyword arguments:
    D - the D matrix
    P - the Pi matrix
    s - the source vertex
    t - the destination vertex
    """

    if D[s][t] == math.inf:
        # No path exists from s to t.
        return math.inf, []

    # Build the path from s to t using the predecessors matrix P.
    path = [s]
    while s != t:
        s = P[s][t]
        path.append(s)
    # Compute the weight of the path.
    w = D[path[0]][path[-1]]
    return w, path
```

But when I try to test this function errors happen

```
G = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix(4)
G.add_edge(0, 1, 2)
G.add_edge(1, 2, 3)
G.add_edge(2, 3, 1)

D, P = G.floyd_warshall()
w, path = pair_shortest_path(D, P, 0, 3)

print("Shortest path weight:", w)  # Output: Shortest path weight: 6
print("Shortest path:", path)  # Output: Shortest path: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

```
s = P[s][t]
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType

I think that problem is in predecessors matrix called P in my code or I implement wrongly my shortest_path function.

Comment: Also in the floyd_warshall() method, if there is an edge directly joining `i` and `j`, and that edge is the shortest path between them, what is the eventual value of `P[i][j]`?

Comment: Here is what I get in P matrix when I test my floyd func: Matrix:
[0, 5, inf, 10]
[5, 0, 3, inf]
[inf, 3, 0, 1]
[10, inf, 1, 0]
Shortest distances:
[0, 5, 8, 9]
[5, 0, 3, 4]
[8, 3, 0, 1]
[9, 4, 1, 0]
Predecessors:
[None, None, 1, 2]
[None, None, None, 2]
[1, None, None, None]
[2, 2, None, None]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code:

- `P[i][j]` should be initialised to `i` when there is an edge between `i` and `j` or when `i` and `j` are equal (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Pseudocode_%5B11%5D)). So extend that initialisation code as follows:

  ```
      P = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
      # Complete initialisation
      for i in range(n):
          for j in range(n):
              if D[i][j] < math.inf:
                  P[i][j] = i
  ```
- In the loop the improvement `P[i][j] = k` is not correct. Note that when execution gets here, we know that the path **via** `k` is shorter than what we had so far, but that doesn't mean `k` is the one-but-last node to visit on the shortest path from `i` to `j`. It only means that `k` is *somewhere* along that path. The correct assignment is `P[i][j] = P[k][j]` (See again the Wikipedia link above), where we say that the last-but-one node on the path is the last-but-one one on the path from `k` to `j` (since we will pass via `k`). Make that correction here:

  ```
                  if D[i][k] + D[k][j] < D[i][j]:
                      D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j]
                      P[i][j] = P[k][j]  # corrected
  ```
- In `pair_shortest_path` you should not take `P[s][t]`, because that is a *predecessor*, i.e. the one-but-last node on the path from `s` to `t`. Instead we need the *successor* of `s` on that path. To get that info, we should look at the inverse -- at `P[t][s]`. The corrected code:

  ```
  path = [s]
  while s != t:
      s = P[t][s]  # corrected: look at reverse path
      path.append(s)
  ```

With those corrections it should work.

**One final remark:** the Floyd-Warschall algorithm is more useful with *directed* graphs that can have *negative* weights. As your graph construction code always adds the same edge in both directions, making it an undirected graph, the graph cannot have negative weights -- this would create cycles that would make a path infinitely *lighter*. And thus this algorithm cannot show its strength in comparison with other algorithms, like Dijkstra's which will perform better for such graphs.

Answer (score -1):

You need to learn how to
[debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Inserting a print debug will reveal:

```
    print(np.array(D), "\n")
    print(np.array(P), "\n")
    while s != t:
        P[s]
        print(f"s: {s}, t: {t},", P[s], "-> ", (P[s][t]))
        s = P[s][t]
        path.append(s)
```

output

```
[[0 2 5 6]
 [2 0 3 4]
 [5 3 0 1]
 [6 4 1 0]] 

[[None None 1 2]
 [None None None 2]
 [1 None None None]
 [2 2 None None]] 

s: 0, t: 3, [None, None, 1, 2] ->  2
s: 2, t: 3, [1, None, None, None] ->  None
Traceback ...
    P[s]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

> debugged my code

The code that produces the predecessor matrix is not yet bug free.
The graph G is fully connected, yet the matrix indicates
that from some nodes there exists no path to certain other nodes.
Contrast what your code does against the networkx
[implementation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.dense.floyd_warshall_predecessor_and_distance.html).
Source code is available from the documentation page.

Your `D` distance matrix looks nice enough.
But you will want to improve how you produce and navigate
the `P` predecessor matrix.

Hint: Get graphviz or
[networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)
to render these datastructures for you, so you can sanity check the results.

Comment: Thanks you for hint but I know what it contains and I also debugged my code. I need know how to avoid error